# Apex can not remove multiple spaces in String

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am trying to remove all spaces from the following string:

```
howabountnow.com,,,itsme.com,,,name,,,hello.com,,,asdasdasdasd.asdasdasda,: :: :;;     ;;; ::   :: :; ; ;,, ,,, ,,, asdasd.asd,,, ,,,asdsadas,,,dilyan
```

and from the place where there are multiple spaces it is removed only one space and the result is:

```
replaceAll('\s+', '');
replaceAll('[ ]+', '');
replace(' ', '');
```

and few more similar expressions.

At the moment I'm using the following source code:

```
String domain = accountObj.Domain__c;
System.debug('domain ' + domain);
integer spaceInd = domain.indexOf(' ');
System.debug('spaceInd1: ' + spaceInd);
while (spaceInd > -1) {
    domain = domain.replace(' ', '');
    spaceInd = domain.indexOf(' ');
    System.debug('spaceInd: ' + spaceInd);
}
System.debug('domain1 ' + domain);
```

When I start the code in debug log I get the following:

```
USER_DEBUG|[198]|DEBUG|domain howabountnow.com,,,itsme.com,,,name,,,hello.com,,,asdasdasdasd.asdasdasda,: :: :;;     ;;; ::   :: :; ; ;,, ,,, ,,, asdasd.asd,,, ,,,asdsadas,,,dilyan
```

USER_DEBUG|[203]|DEBUG|spaceInd1: 75
USER_DEBUG|[207]|DEBUG|spaceInd: -1
USER_DEBUG|[209]|DEBUG|domain1 howabountnow.com,,,itsme.com,,,name,,,hello.com,,,asdasdasdasd.asdasdasda,::::;;    ;;;::  :::;;;,,,,,,,,asdasd.asd,,,,,,asdsadas,,,dilyan

Could you please advise how to remove all spaces from the String or replace them with a single space in apex?

Regards,

Diyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [deleteWhiteSpace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_deleteWhitespace) string method?

This unit test passes for me :

```
@isTest
private class StringTest 
{
     static testMethod void myStringTest() 
     {
          String test = 'howabountnow.com,,,itsme.com,,,name,,,hello.com,,,asdasdasdasd.asdasdasda,: :: :;;     ;;; ::   :: :; ; ;,, ,,, ,,, asdasd.asd,,, ,,,asdsadas,,,dilyan';
          String noSpaces = test.deleteWhitespace();
          System.assertEquals(noSpaces, 'howabountnow.com,,,itsme.com,,,name,,,hello.com,,,asdasdasdasd.asdasdasda,::::;;;;;:::::;;;,,,,,,,,asdasd.asd,,,,,,asdsadas,,,dilyan');
     }
}
```